# Undo git fast forward merge

Tags: git, git-merge, fast-forward

I have this situation : 
Working on some testBranch for some time and I wanted to sync with master so I did
git checkout testBranch and
git merge master/testBranch

So now my branch is synced with master but then I found out that I want to undo that merge and problem is that merge is done with fast forward and now my commit history is mixed with master commits and testBranch commits and I don't know how to revert to state before merge on my testBranch.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Are commits merged from `master/testBranch` located *at the tip* of your `testBranch` or you've already managed to record several your own local commits on top of what has been merged?  The way to recover heavily depends on this.

Comment: Any reason you're not satisfied with my answer?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`git reflog show testBranch`

should show the Fast-forward merge as last item (`{0}`).
After making sure this is the case, checkout `testBranch` and then just do

`git reset --keep testBranch@{1}`

to revert to the previous state.

Comment: This is a good answer. I would add that it's important to make sure you checkout testBranch before running `git reset`

Comment: An easy-to-understand and nice approach! This should be marked as an answer

Comment: Note for PowerShell users: You must run last command as `git reset --keep 'testBranch@{1}'`

Answer (score 5):

If you know of a revision in which you want your local testBranch, it is as simple as:

```
git checkout testBranch
git reset --hard <revision>
```

If you have changes mixed in like (oldest on top):

```
<point>
<your_change_a>
<change_from_someone_else>
<your_change_b>
<testBranch>
```

You could:

```
git checkout testBranch
git reset --hard <point>
git cherry-pick <your_change_a>
git cherry-pick <your_change_b>
```

Comment: This should work. I would also recommend using a Git graphical viewer such as gitg or gitk to get a good overview of the changes you want to undo.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have found another solution (I haven't try yours but I suppose it works to).  Solution is found in this blog : http://blog.tplus1.com/blog/2011/09/23/undo-a-fast-forward-git-merge/  ... hope it helps someone else to :) ...